# NameError in Python when passing argument

Tags: python

In this very simple code, I am getting an error saying parrot not defined. Parrot is the argument i am passing. Can someone help?

```
def adverbly(word):
    return (word + "ly")


adverbly (parrot)
```

Comment: is `parrot` a variable defined elsewhere or did you mean "parrot"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NameError` is thrown when you try to access an undefined variable.
Thus, you have to choose one of these options:

1. define `parrot` variable and then pass it as an argument:

```
var = 'parrot'
adverbly(var)
```

2. pass a value as an argument to your function:

```
adverbly('parrot')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def adverbly(word):
    return (word + "ly")

adverbly('parrot')
```